# why the boundary of loop is zero?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

In simplices complex, it is known that **boundary of boundary is zero**

$$\partial_{n-1} \partial_{n} \sigma_{0,\ldots,n} = 0$$
where $\sigma_{0,\ldots,n}$ is a *n-simplice* consists of $n+1$ point, which by definition, it is a *convex hull* of those point.

Someone showed that on the youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XOZN3XZdoO0&t=2324s) about
$$\sigma_1 + \sigma_1 = 0$$

But why? I cannot see it even in intuition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That video is working with chains with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  So, $\sigma_1+\sigma_1=2\sigma_1$ is $0$ since the coefficients on the individual simplices are considered as integers mod $2$ and so $2$ is the same as $0$.

It is possible to instead consider chains with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$, and then $\sigma_1+\sigma_1$ would not be $0$.  If you do that, though, you have to modify the definition of the boundary operators to include some minus signs and so the boundary of a loop based at $\sigma_1$ would turn out to be $\sigma_1-\sigma_1$ instead of $\sigma_1+\sigma_1$ (one of the endpoints gets counted with a minus sign).

Comment: Thanks Eric. But I failed to find the place she mentioned Z/2Z? Did you find it or it is common sense in that area?

Comment: She mentions it at about 21:50.

Comment: Oh I missed that part. Thanks!!